# how to save data to local storage and keep data after refresh in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, local-storage, state

i am trying to save searched recipes data to local storage so when the user refreshes the data from the last searched recipe will be there.

i tried setting recipes data to local storage when new search request is fulfilled and set recipes state to the data from the local storage but when the page or component is refreshed the local storage is set to the initial state which is a empty array.

```
export function Explore() {

const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState<any[]>([]);
   

const handleSearch = async () => {
        if (search) {
            const recipesData = await fetchData(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=KEY&query=${search}&number=100`);
            setRecipes(recipesData.results);
        }
        setSearch('');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const data = window.localStorage.getItem('recipes');
        if (data !== null) setRecipes(JSON.parse(data));
        console.log(data)
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        window.localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes))
    },[recipes])
```

Comment: Why do you have two `useEffect`?

Comment: One has dependencies and one doesn't.

Comment: Add a console.log to the second effect to see when these are firing. The problem I think it the second effect that sets local storage is calling on page load (which is normal behavior) as well as when recipes changes. Remember, JavaScript is not good at doing thing synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two effects. Both will run right after the component mounts. Because the `[]` one comes before the `[recipes]` one, the `[recipes]` one will run second. At that point, the first effect will have already run and there'll be a pending state update - but the second effect's `recipes` identifier references the value on mount, which is the empty array - so the storage value is cleared.

While you could fix it by reversing the order of the effects in the component, a better approach would be to use the functional version of `useState` to retrieve the data from storage if it exists, ditching the first effect entirely.

```
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState<any[]>(
  () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recipes') ?? '[]')
);
```

Also, since you're using TypeScript, you should really try to work within the type system rather than ignoring it - figure out the proper type of the `recipes` state and use that instead of `any`. (`any` defeats the whole purpose of TypeScript)

Comment: Nice answer. I was thinking the same thing. Also, good point on TS, lol. I just don't use it. Too much typing, but yeah, why use it only to ignore it? Useless extra code and typing.